# Read a large CSV order book

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, csv

I am trying to read entries of my CSV file into an entries vector whose data type is object `OrderBookEntry`, which is an object that stores the tokenized variables from the CSV line which itself is converted through the function `tokenise`. My problem is that my CSV file has around a million lines and it takes over 30 seconds to load; how can I reduce this?

This is my code that actually reads lines from the file and converts them into entries.

```
    std::vector<OrderBookEntry> CSVReader::readCSV(std::string csvFilename)
    {
        std::vector<OrderBookEntry> entries;
    
        std::ifstream csvFile{csvFilename};
        
        std::string line;
        if (csvFile.is_open())
        {
            while(std::getline(csvFile, line))
            {
                try {
                    OrderBookEntry obe = stringsToOBE(tokenise(line, ','));
                    entries.push_back(obe);
                    //std::cout << "pushing entry" << std::endl;
                }catch(const std::exception& e)
                {
                    //std::cout << "CSVReader::readCSV bad data"  << std::endl;
                }
            }// end of while
        }    
    
        std::cout << "CSVReader::readCSV read " << entries.size() << " entries"  << 
        std::endl;
        return entries; 
    }
```

This is the part of my code that tokenises the read line:

```
    std::vector<std::string> CSVReader::tokenise(std::string csvLine, char separator)
    {
       std::vector<std::string> tokens;
       signed int start, end;
       std::string token;
        start = csvLine.find_first_not_of(separator, 0);
        do{
            end = csvLine.find_first_of(separator, start);
            if (start == csvLine.length() || start == end) break;
            if (end >= 0) token = csvLine.substr(start, end - start);
            else token = csvLine.substr(start, csvLine.length() - start);
            tokens.push_back(token);
        start = end + 1;
        }while(end > 0);
    
       return tokens; 
    }
```

This is the part of my code that converts the tokens into a suitable object to work with:

```
    OrderBookEntry CSVReader::stringsToOBE(std::vector<std::string> tokens)
    {
        double price, amount;
    
        if (tokens.size() != 5) // bad
        {
            //std::cout << "Bad line " << std::endl;
            throw std::exception{};
        }
        // we have 5 tokens
        try {
             price = std::stod(tokens[3]);
             amount = std::stod(tokens[4]);
        }catch(const std::exception& e){
            std::cout << "Bad float! " << tokens[3]<< std::endl;
            std::cout << "Bad float! " << tokens[4]<< std::endl; 
            throw;        
        }
    
        OrderBookEntry obe{price, 
                            amount, 
                            tokens[0],
                            tokens[1], 
                            OrderBookEntry::stringToOrderBookType(tokens[2])};
    
        return obe; 
    }
```

Do advise on how I can make the code faster.

Comment: What is OrderBookEntry?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We could provide even more help with optimization if we knew more about the code. Please don't change this question but in the future, the more code you provide the better we can help you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: In addition to the answers below, when transitioning to `string_view` use methods from `<charconv>` like `from_chars` they convert numbers much faster than `stod`. Assuming, your compiler supports them ofc. Also, why `amount` is a double? Shouldn't it be integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid throwing exceptions if they are not exceptional

You throw exceptions on parse errors, but in C++, exceptions are free if you don't `throw` them (i.e., you don't pay for the `try`-`catch`), but they can be very slow when you do `throw`. So you should only use that for exceptional situations, as the name implies. If your input file has lots of empty lines or lines with comments instead of data, then you throw exceptions a lot, slowing down your code significantly. Consider using a different way to signal that a line could not be parsed, for example by returning a [`std::optional<OrderBookEntry>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) from `stringsToOBE()`.

## Avoid memory allocations

`std::vector` and `std::string` perform memory allocations under the hood. As slepic mentioned, pass `std::string` by const reference where possible. But you can also consider using [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). In particular, `tokenise()` could take `csvLine` as a `std::string_view` and return a `std::vector<std::string_view>`. This way it doesn't pay for string allocations.

If you know each line should have exactly 5 tokens, then you could also consider returning a [`std::array<std::string_view, 5>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Parse errors may be legitimately considered exceptional, depending on whether you expect input to be valid or not.

Answer (score 5):

Don't pass strings and vectors by value. Pass them by const reference.
When you pass them by value, they need to be copied which is a waste of time and resources.

```
std::vector<std::string> CSVReader::tokenise(const std::string & csvLine, char separator);
```

and

```
OrderBookEntry CSVReader::stringsToOBE(const std::vector<std::string> & tokens);
```

and lastly here, but here it is not going to be so big problem in terms of performance because it is only called once.

```
std::vector<OrderBookEntry> CSVReader::readCSV(const std::string & csvFilename);
```

Also make sure that OrderBookEntry constructor does not suffer the same problem.

Also when you are using vector you effectively copy the strings again if you push_back them to the vector, you better emplace_back them. Or even better, use `std::string_view`.

In either case, the same goes for vector of order book entries. You should emplace_back the entries to avoid copying the entries.

```
entries.emplace_back(stringsToOBE(tokenise(line, ',')));
```